# react-native-camera not firing on Android

Tags: android, react-native, barcode-scanner, react-native-camera

I am using react-native-camera to scan barcodes. On iOS, where I started developing, everything works well as expected. On Android though, it will just not fire `onBarcodeRead` when a barcode is focused with the camera.

The relevant piece of code is the following:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          ref={(ref) => {
            setCamera(ref);
          }}
          aspect={1}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          captureAudio={false}
          onBarCodeRead={processBarcode}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}>
          <View>{mainInteractionElement}</View>
        </RNCamera>
      </View>
```

The function `processBarcode` will just not be fired on Android. I have already read through all (old) answers around the barcode scanning not working on Android but nothing described helped me (e.g. upgrading to the latest version, setting the aspect ratio, ...).

Does anyone maybe have a solution?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Why don't you use [Expo Camera](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/)

Comment: Because I am not using Expo. I don’t think Expo Camera works without using Expo, right?

Comment: You can use it in Bare Workflow as well.

Comment: Ok thank you! Of course I would rather like to use react-native-camera if possible as I have already built a big feature set around it so I would be happy if someone would have a solution for react-native-camera as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I did not get it running. In the end, I decided to use `onBarCodeRead` on iOS and `onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected` on Android. That was the only way I got it running on both platforms.